# Is there any research, theory, or anything which shows how much of a market has to be in power of a few companies to be a force against free market?

Tags: monopoly, oligopoly, free-market

According to [Free market](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_market)

> a free market is a system in which the prices for goods and services
>   are determined by the open market and by consumers. In a free market,
>   the laws and forces of supply and demand are free from any
>   intervention by a government or other authority and from all forms of
>   economic privilege, monopolies and artificial scarcities

Being monopolies and oligopolies a force against free market, is there any study, theory or anything which shows how much of a market has to be in power of a few companies for them to be able to alter the free market laws/rules?

Comment: Are you aware of the [Herfindahl-Hirschman Index](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/h/hhi.asp)?

Comment: @ Herr K. HHI is just an accounting mesure as far as market power is concerned it doesn't say much. That is why Competition Authorities only use it as a scrrening device. For example if a market is open to "hit-and-run" operations even a monopolist cannot charge much above marginal costs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quote in the question isn't really rigorous about what a free market is, but it talks about monopolies and artificial scarcities, so I am interpreting the efficient outcome with price equal to marginal cost as being one necessary feature of what they understand as a free market.

---

Let's look at the cournot model of competition. There are $n$ firms, each with idiosyncratic marginal cost $c_i$. Each firm simultaneously chooses its output (supply) quantity, $q_i$. Given consumers' demand, this results in some market price $P(Q)$, where $Q=\sum_{i=1}^n q_i$ is the total industry output. We would expect the demand curve to be downward sloping: $P'(Q)<0$.

Thus, a firm's profits are
$$\pi_i(q_i,\mathbf{q}_{-i})=\left(P(Q)-c_i\right)q_i.$$
The first-order condition for maximisation of profit is
$$\frac{\partial\pi_i}{\partial q_i}=P(Q)-c_i+\frac{\partial P(Q)}{\partial q_i}=0.$$
Noting that $$\frac{\partial P(Q)}{\partial q_i}=\frac{\partial P(Q)}{\partial Q},$$
the first-order condition can be re-written as
$$\frac{P(Q)-c_i}{c_i}=-\frac{\partial P(Q)}{\partial Q}\frac{Q}{P(Q)}\frac{q_i}{Q},$$
$$\frac{P(Q)-c_i}{c_i}=-\frac{1}{\eta}m_i,$$
where $\eta$ is the price elasticity of demand and $m_i=q_i/Q$ is firm $i$'s market share.

The left-hand side measures a firm's price-cost margin, or its market power. We can compute the average market power in the industry by weighting each firm by its market share:

$$\text{avg market power}=\sum_i m_i \frac{P(Q)-c_i}{c_i}=-\frac{\sum_i m_i^2}{\eta}.$$

Note that $\sum_i m_i^2$ is the HHI index for the market. So this equation tells us that the average market power in an industry will be positively related to the HHI. **For any positive HHI, there will be a positive mark-up and the market will deviate from the perfectly competitive outcome in which artificial scarcities do not exist.** Put differently, only if there is an infinite number of firms, each controling an infinitely small share of the industry do we obtain the textbook perfect competition outcome.